# LINQ to Entities not ordering correctly

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a function that runs a somewhat complex LINQ query, but I've verified that the simplified code below also has the problem. I specifically tell the query to order by `RequiredDate`, which is a `DateTime`. This is completely ignored, however--the sorting actually occurs by another property, `PONumber`. The database is all random test data, so nothing is ordered except the `Id` column. I'm not sure why the other property is being used instead of the column I'm trying to sort by. I use Kendo UI, so the `IEnumerable` is converted to a Kendo type in the controller, but the LINQ to Entities query returns the incorrect order. What is causing this problem?

(simplified versions are below)

Class:

```
public partial class PurchaseOrder : BaseEntity
{
    public virtual int PONumber { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime RequiredDate { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
public PurchaseOrderMap()
{
    ToTable("PurchaseOrder");
    HasKey(c => c.Id);
    Property(u => u.PONumber).IsRequired();
    Property(u => u.RequiredDate).IsRequired();
}
```

Service (this fetches the data):

```
public virtual IEnumerable<PurchaseOrder> GetAllPOs()
{
    var query = _poRepository.Table;
    query = query.Where(p => p.Shipment == null);

    query = query.OrderBy(p => p.RequiredDate);
    return query;
}
```

Function is called in the controller by this code. `DataSourceRequest` and `DataSourceResult` are functions in Kendo UI.

```
public ActionResult POList([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
{
    var pos = _poService.GetAllPOs();
    DataSourceResult result = pos.ToDataSourceResult(request, o => PreparePOModelForList(o));

    return Json(result);
}
```

The actual query against the DB (courtesy of SQL Profiler) is:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id],
    [Extent1].[PONumber] AS [PONumber],
    [Extent1].[RequiredDate] AS [RequiredDate],
    [Extent1].[LastUpdateDate] AS [LastUpdateDate],
    FROM    [dbo].[PurchaseOrder] AS [Extent1]
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[PONumber] ASC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Based on the `OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY` I'm guessing you have some additional logic somewhere which is attempting to apply pagination via the `Skip()` and `Take()` methods.  My guess is you do some additional sorting there that you are missing.  I can't prove that based on the code you have given, but try to figure out what is generating your `OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT ...` and I suspect you'll find your answer.

Comment: I agree with @CodingGorilla.  Maybe the Kendo UI is the culprit.  Note that you are returning an `IQuerable<PurchaseOrder>` (as an `IEnumerable<PurchaseOrder>`).  So the final query that will be translated to SQL can still be altered.  You could try `return query.ToList();` to see what happens.

Comment: @CodingGorilla That's exactly what it was, thank you! I'm still not the best at dealing with LINQ / EF queries, I missed that an `IQueryable` is returned which is actually instantiated by the Kendo function, which has a different way of sorting. I've updated the OP with the full function instead so it's more clear, and I'm more than happy to select your answer if you post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY I'm guessing you have some additional logic somewhere which is attempting to apply pagination via the Skip() and Take() methods. My guess is you do some additional sorting there that you are missing. I can't prove that based on the code you have given, but try to figure out what is generating your OFFSET ... FETCH NEXT ... and I suspect you'll find your answer.